# MongoDB Replica Set secondary node (not reachable/healthy)

Tags: mongodb, nosql, database-administration

- List item

I am currently running a MongoDB replica set with 1x Primary, 1x Secondary, and 1x Arbiter, all hosted on AWS EC2 Instances. I recently took the Secondary down to upgrade the hardware. On reboot, it had a different IP address (as expected).

Once rebooted, I restarted `mongod` on the Secondary and updated our DNS so that mongo2.**************.com now points to the new IP address.

I am able to connect from the primary to the secondary

```
mongo1.**************.com:~$ curl -ik mongo2.**************.com:27017
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 84

It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Same works to and from the secondary.

However, when I do `rs.status()` whilst connected to the replica set, I an error in the connection to the Secondary.

```
{
    "set" : "myReplicaSet",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:29:43.308Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(-1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 23,
            "name" : "mongo1.**************.com:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 13108,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1543588183, 6),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:29:43.000Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1543575397, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-11-30T10:56:37.000Z"),
            "configVersion" : 788876,
            "self" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 24,
            "name" : "mongoarb.**************.com:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 12785,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:29:41.491Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:29:43.056Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "configVersion" : 788876
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 25,
            "name" : "mongo2.**************.com:27017",
            "health" : 0.0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:29:41.754Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us",
            "configVersion" : -1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Here is the output of `rs.conf()` when connected to the replica set via Robo 3T

```
{
    "_id" : "myReplicaSet",
    "version" : 788876,
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 23,
            "host" : "mongo1.**************.com:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1.0,
            "tags" : {},
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 24,
            "host" : "mongoarb.**************.com:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : true,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1.0,
            "tags" : {},
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 25,
            "host" : "mongo2.**************.com:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1.0,
            "tags" : {},
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {},
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to make a Direct Connection to the Secondary via Robo 3T.

In the logs of the Primary Node, I see the following error:

`2018-11-30T15:29:17.519+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to mongo2.**************.com:27017; InvalidReplicaSetConfig: Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us`

All nodes are running Mongo Version 3.2.19

How can I get the replica set to connect to the secondary?

Comment: Did you get any luck with this one? I have the same issue on V4.4.14 with a very similar configuration (VM installation, 1 primary, 1 arbiter, and 2 secondaries). When I try to add another replica I get "Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us". 

The only difference I see with the other nodes is that this one has a longer Ping (32 ms vs 8 for the others)

Comment: @YlliPrifti In the end I went for rebooting the erroring secondary node and reinstalling MongoDB on the node. Pretty much just 'Turning it off an again'